# is there a Collection Subscription Inheritance passed onto child templates

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Consider below hierarchy of templates,

1. '**A**' has 2 template 'B' and 'C'.
2. '**B**' has 2 templates '**D**' and '**E**'.

my question is whether the meteor collection subcription made in template '**A**' is available in the helper for template '**E**' since '**A**' has '**B**' and '**B**' has '**E**'?

> ***NOTE***: if **YES/NO** why?

Comment: Do you want to access the documents or the subscription handle in your E template?

Comment: Subscription handles

Answer (score 1):

will that data be available? probably.

if template A is setting up the sub in its onCreated(), and attached to "this", then that means the sub will go away when the template is destroyed.

and if the sub-template is set up like this:

```
<template name="A">
  {{> B}}
</template>
```

... template A is not destroyed while B is rendered.

this means that template B should be able to do a find() in minimongo and see that data that A subscribed to.

personally, i prefer to pass down from A to B any data that A "owns" that B uses. but that works better in a non-reactive scenario. if B needs to find() data and expects it to be reactive, then i'll typically have B also subscribe to that data. imho, it's more clear in that case to have B also subscribe, because if it's taken out of the A context, it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

The data is available as a helper in the child templates if you pass the data to them.

You can do:

```
{{> childTemplate post=post}}
```

And then

```
<template name="childTemplate">
  {{post.title}}
</template>
```

Comment: what you have specified is by mentioning it as a parameter, but is it not implicitly taken into the scope?

Answer (score 0):

The subscription data is bounded to the scope you subscribe to.
You can `Template.instance().subscribe('subscription_name')`. The data will then be available to the Template instance.

Also also can `Meteor.subscribe('subscription_name')`. The data will then be scoped to the Meteor environment. In this case the will data be accessible from the child templates as well. This isn't recommendable for sensitive data, though.

Last alternative is, like in Afifs answer, to give the child template the data with a parameter, which is effective and neat.